# Beautifulsoup4 - not selcting all instances of span class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape data from a website that uses non-specific span classes to format/display content. The pages present information about chemical products and each product is described within a single div class.
I first parsed by that div class and am working to pull the data I need from there.  I have been able to get many things but the parts I cant seem to pull are within the span class "ppisreportspan" 
If you look at the code, you will note that it appears multiple times within each chemical description.

```
<tr>
    <td><h4 id='stateprod'>MAINE STATE PRODUCT REPORT</h4><hr class='report'><span style="color:Maroon;" Class="subtitle">Company Number: </span><span style='color:black;' Class="subtitle">38</span><br /><span Class="subtitle">MONSANTO COMPANY                                                                                    <br/>800 N. LINDBERGH BOULEVARD                                  <br/>MAIL STOP FF4B                                              <br/>ST LOUIS&nbsp;MO&nbsp;63167-0001<br/></span><br/><span style="color:Maroon;" Class="subtitle">Number of Currently Registered Products: </span><span style='color:black; font-size:14px' class="subtitle">80</span><br /><br/><p class='noprint'><img alt='' src='images/epalogo.png' />&nbsp;&nbsp;View the label in the US EPA Pesticide Product Label System (PPLS).<br /><img alt='' src='images/alstar.png' />&nbsp;&nbsp;View the label in the Accepted Labels State Tracking and Repository (ALSTAR).<br /></p>
        <hr class='report'>
            <div class='nopgbrk'>
                <span class='ppisreportspanprodname'>PRECEPT INSECTICIDE </span>
                <br/>EPA Registration Number: <a href = "http://iaspub.epa.gov/apex/pesticides/f?p=PPLS:102:::NO::P102_REG_NUM:100-1075" target='blank'>100-1075-524 <img alt='EPA PPLS Link' src='images/pplslink.png'/></a>
                <span class='line-break'></span>
                <span class=ppisProd>ME Product Number: </span>
                <**span class="ppisreportspan"**>2014000996</span>
                <br />Registration Year: &nbsp;&nbsp;<**span class="ppisreportspan"**>2019</span>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Type: &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="ppisreportspan">RESTRICTED</span><br/><br/>
                <table width='100%'>
                    <tr>
                        <td width='13%'>Percent</td>
                        <td style='width:87%;align:left'>Active Ingredient</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="ppisreportspan">3.0000</span></td>
                        <td><span class="ppisreportspan">Tefluthrin (128912)</span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table><hr />
        </div>

        <div class='nopgbrk'>
            <span class='ppisreportspanprodname' >ACCELERON IC-609 INSECTICIDE SEED TREATMENT FOR CORN</span>
            <br/>EPA Registration Number: <a href = "http://iaspub.epa.gov/apex/pesticides/f?p=PPLS:102:::NO::P102_REG_NUM:264-789" target='blank'>264-789-524 <img alt='EPA PPLS Link' src='images/pplslink.png'/>
            </a><span class='line-break'></span>
            <span class=ppisProd>ME Product Number: <a href = "alstar_label.aspx?LabelId=116671" target = 'blank'>2009005053</span>
                <img alt='ALSTAR Link' src='images/alstar.png'/></a>
                <br />Registration Year: &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="ppisreportspan">2019</span>
                <br/>
                <table width='100%'>
                    <tr>
                        <td width='13%'>Percent</td>
                        <td style='width:87%;align:left'>Active Ingredient</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="ppisreportspan">48.0000</span></td>
                        <td><span class="ppisreportspan">Clothianidin (44309)</span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table><hr />
            </div>
```

This sample includes two chemicals.  One has an "alstar" ID and link and one does not.  Both have registration years.  Those are the data points that are hanging me up.

You may also note that there is a 10 digit code stored in "ppisreportspan" in the first example.  I was able to extract that as part of the "ppisProd" span for nay record that doesn't have the Alstar link.  I don't understand why, but it reinforces the point that it seems my parsing process ignores that span class.

I have tried various methods for the last 2 days based on all kinds of different answers on SO, so I can't possibly list them all. I seem to be able to either get anything from the first "span" to the  end on the last span, or I get "nonetype" errors or empty lists.

This one gets the closest:

It returns the correct spans for many div chunks but it still skips (returns blank tuple []) for any of the ones that have alstar links like the second one in the example.
[picture showing data and then a series of three sets of empty brackets where the data should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgykT.png)

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import re

url = input('Enter URL:')
hand = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(hand, 'html.parser')
#create a list of chunks by product (div)
products = soup.find_all('div' , class_ ='nopgbrk')
print(type(products))
print(len(products))

tempalstars =[]
rptspanclasses = []
regyears = []
alstarIDs = []
asltrlinks = []
# read the span tags
for product in products:
    tempalstar = product.find_all('span', class_= "ppisreportspan")
    tempalstars.append(tempalstar)

print(tempalstar)
```

Ultimately, I want to be able to select the text for the year as well as the Alstar link out of these span statements for each div chunk, but I will be cross that bridge when I can get the code finding all the instances of that class.

Alternately - Is there some easier way I can get the Registration year and the Alstar link (eg. `<a href = "alstar_label.aspx?LabelId=116671" target = 'blank'>2009005053</span> <img alt='ALSTAR Link' src='images/alstar.png'/></a>`) rather than what I am trying to do?

I am using Python 3.7.2 and Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the URL of the site you want parse the information? As I've understood, you want to extract Product Number, Year and Alstar Link only...

Comment: Hi Andrej-  There are other points I also want to extract, but I am not having trouble with them.  The page is also tricky, as you have to go in and do three levels of search to get a results set to be processed, and even then its tricky to save in a way that doesn't take you back to the higher level.  The search is first by state and then by company and then you have to display one of two choices.  The web address doesn't change during those last 2 steps. http://npirspublic.ceris.purdue.edu/state/company.aspx  I used State: Maine & company: Monsanto Co.

Comment: I contacted NPIRS to see if they have an API, but haven't heard back.  In the mean time I am working from saved files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get some data from this site. All you need to know is the company number, in case of `monsanto`, the number is `38` (this number is shown in after selecting `Maine` and typing `monsanto` in the search box:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_1 = 'http://npirspublic.ceris.purdue.edu/state/state_menu.aspx?state=ME'
url_2 = 'http://npirspublic.ceris.purdue.edu/state/company.aspx'

company_name = 'monsanto'
company_number = '38'

with requests.session() as s:
    r = s.get(url_1)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    data = {i['name']: '' for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    for i in soup.select('input[value]'):
        data[i['name']] = i['value']

    data['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$search'] = 'company'
    data['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBoxInput1'] = company_name

    r = s.post(url_1, data=data)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    data = {i['name']: '' for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    for i in soup.select('input[value]'):
        data[i['name']] = i['value']

    data = {k: v for k, v in data.items() if not k.startswith('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$')}
    data['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1${}'.format(company_number)] = 'Display+Products'

    r = s.post(url_2, data=data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    for div in soup.select('.nopgbrk'):
        #extract name
        print(div.select_one('.ppisreportspanprodname').text)

        #extract ME product number:
        s = ''.join(re.findall(r'\d{10}', div.text))
        print(s)

        #extract alstar link
        s = div.select_one('a[href*="alstar_label.aspx"]')
        if s:
            print(s['href'])
        else:
            print('No ALSTAR link')

        #extract Registration year:
        s = div.find(text=lambda t: 'Registration Year:' in t)
        if s:
            print(s.next.text)
        else:
            print('No registration year.')

        print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
PRECEPT INSECTICIDE                                                                                                                                                                                     
2014000996
No ALSTAR link
2019
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCELERON IC-609 INSECTICIDE SEED TREATMENT FOR CORN                                                                                                                                                    
2009005053
alstar_label.aspx?LabelId=117531
2019
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCELERON D-342 FUNGICIDE SEED TREATMENT                                                                                                                                                                
2015000498
alstar_label.aspx?LabelId=117538
2019
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCELERON DX-309                                                                                                                                                                                        
2009005026
alstar_label.aspx?LabelId=117559
2019
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

... and so on.
```

Comment: So this is parsed as xml? (Thats why you used soup lxml?) I toyed with that idea and tried different things with that, but I thought xml was by nature all labeled, which this is definitely not.

Comment: @jarg No, it's parsed as HTML document. You can substitute `lxml` for `html.parser` and it will work the same. It just happens that I have `lxml` installed on my computer.

Comment: I'm going to try to work out what "r" and "s" are so I can interpret this within the framework of what I have already done.  Thanks for your help.  It is miles and miles over my head, but I will see what I can make of it :) Thanks-

Comment: Is there any reference you can direct me toward that can help me understand what your ```lamda t``` command is doing on the registration year?  Your code is very elegant, but I would like to fully understand it for future reference. From what I can find lamda acts some sort of shorthand.  Does the 't' mean something standard in that instance like _text_, or have you assigned it a meaning through some wizardry right in that line? Thanks again!

Comment: @jarg You can learn about BeautifulSoup api here https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/  lambda is shorthand for anonymous function, you can think of it as one-line `def`

Comment: I have been spending lots of time at crummy.com, but I believe lambda is a python command rather than a BS4 command,  I have done more testing and see that the t is assigned meaning in that line of code as I can replace it with anything. I have seen various tutorials using lambda for math.  I will keep searching for one that explains more about text functions such as what you did.  Thanks for your patience.